# Build Error Zeppelin 0.6.1

Tags: maven, apache-zeppelin

I'm getting a maven build error building Apache Zeppelin branch 0.6.1 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project zeppelin-spark_2.10: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.zeppelin:zeppelin-spark_2.10:jar:0.6.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.apache.zeppelin:zeppelin-spark-dependencies:jar:0.6.1-SNAPSHOT in apache.snapshots (http://repository.apache.org/snapshots) -> [Help 1]

My build command is:
 $ mvn clean package -Pspark-1.6 -Phadoop-2.6 -Pyarn -Ppyspark -Psparkr -DskipTests

I tried compiling with -U and also removing the ~/.m2/repository

Here's the Zeppelin version:

```
   <groupId>org.apache.zeppelin</groupId>
      <artifactId>zeppelin</artifactId>
      <packaging>pom</packaging>
      <version>0.6.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <name>Zeppelin</name>
      <description>Zeppelin project</description>
      <url>http://zeppelin.apache.org/</url>

Here's maven and Java versions:
    ubuntu@ip-10-0-1-215:~/zeppelin$ mvn -version
    Apache Maven 3.3.7-SNAPSHOT (58348a8971e0fb4cf26a281f1cf0f2ce3af9f0c9; 2015-08-17T08:31:09+00:00)
    Maven home: /home/ubuntu/apps/maven/apache-maven-3.3.x-SNAPSHOT
    Java version: 1.8.0_101, vendor: Oracle Corporation
    Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
    Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
    OS name: "linux", version: "3.13.0-92-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
    ubuntu@ip-10-0-1-215:~/zeppelin$ java -version
    java version "1.8.0_101"
    Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.101-b13, mixed mode)
    ubuntu@ip-10-0-1-215:~/zeppelin$ 

    ubuntu@ip-10-0-1-215:~/zeppelin$ hadoop version
    Hadoop 2.6.4
    Subversion https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop.git -r 5082c73637530b0b7e115f9625ed7fac69f937e6
    Compiled by jenkins on 2016-02-12T09:45Z
    Compiled with protoc 2.5.0
    From source with checksum 8dee2286ecdbbbc930a6c87b65cbc010
    This command was run using /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.6.4.jar
```

Zeppelin branch 0.5.6 build properly:
git clone https://github.com/apache/zeppelin.git -b branch-0.5.6

Comment: why do you use branch 0.5.6 when you wanna build 0.6?

Comment: I wanted to see if it would build.  Also, branch 0.7.0 built and runs.

Comment: If you wanna experience it. Then you need update all the child pom.xml related, include the one for zeppelin-spark-dependencies.

Comment: Is this still the issue?